# Symfony 2.0 with Propel as ORM - Creating Form Classes - The Type class does not exist

Tags: symfony, propel

I already built a form object and then render it in a template inside controller. Now I am trying to build the form in a separate PHP class.

Based on the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-form-creating-form-classes), I have to create a method in the *src/Acme/TaskBundle/Form/Type/TaskType.php*.

But the problem is, I don't have the *../Form/Type/TaskType.php directories*. I tried to do some work around such as create the method inside the Model class, but as expected, it failed.

Is the problem come during the Bundle creation? Or should I create the directories manually?

Answer (score 1):

Manually. It won't create all possible directories for you.